# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Interface customizations

Tags: linux, oracle, interface, business-intelligence, obiee

I am facing problems with interface customizations in the latest OBIEE release.

Is it possible to "hide" the Mobile, VA and BiPublisher options - marked red in the [appendix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp5tk.png).

(Privileges in Administration and roles in EM are configured - users can not access Mobile, BiPub however the buttons are still visible - OBI 11 did not display them afterwards...)

I am looking for a "clean" design.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately up to and including 12.2.1.2 (the current version) the "Visual Analyzer" menu point will keep being rendered even if they permission has been removed from the application role(s) of the user.

Mobile and BIP disappear completely on the other hand.

So the question to be asked is: how did you configure your application roles and policies? Did you reuse vanilla ones? Then it may just be the case that some rights still persist due to ootb inheritance between roles and hence some rights stay even though you think you removed them.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your reply. Editing the application roles and policies in EM did remove mobile and bip. VA menu point will be rendered unless it is unchecked within the installation process of OBI.

Comment: In future releases the removal of the app policy should also remove the menu entry.